# Link does not work after fast refresh or regular refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am building a dashboard where I have an edit button inside `pages/dashboard/index.tsx` file, like so:

```
<Link href={`${pathname}/${slug}`} passHref>
  <a>
    <Edit className="h-4 w-4" />
  </a>
</Link>
```

I also have a `[slug].tsx` file inside `dashboard` folder as well.

When the page loads for the first time (or if I empty cache and hard reload) this link works fine.

However, after fash refresh, or if I do manual regular refresh, the link does not work anymore.

When I inspect the `a` element in the DOM, it looks like the `href` attribute is there in both scenarios. This is hindering my development experience very badly. I wonder if anyone knows why would that happen?

Comment: Why would you remove Next.js from the title? It's the Link component from Next.js framework. It has a special API that behaves differently. I don't understand the point of this edit, seriously.

Comment: That's what tags are used for, see [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Since your question is about Next.js it's implicit that `Link` refers to `next/link`, unless stated otherwise. You could make that clear in the question itself if you want.

Comment: Could you provide a [mre]?